# How to get text from textfield of ios system messages application

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, custom-controls, textfield, message

I am using custom keyboard to convert english written text into urdu or arabic. I am able to convert text written in textfield of within my app but i dont know how to get text written in textfield of system messages app of iphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the text of iMessage messag. Apple does not allow this for privacy reasons.

Comment: one of ios app on appstore is doing this.